# How to get created objects (instances) in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I just did some researches on google but I didn't find an answer to my question.
Is there a way to get the list of the active objects (instances of classes) at runtime?

In my application I need to have single instance classes that needs to be used by different running forms but if I create an instance in the form A, ho do i get control of the same instance in the form B?

Thank you

Comment: There is no list of active objects.

Comment: Form instances are stored at my.application.forms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, your question has 2 parts:
1. How to create single-instance objects.
2. How to have the same object accessible from different forms.

Fortunately for you, there is a solution to both of these problems in one simple and common design pattern called Singleton.
Classes written in the Singleton pattern can only have a single instance, and as you are about to see, as a side effect, this instance is accessible through the entire application.

The simplest way to use the singleton design pattern is this:

`Public Class SingletonClass

Private Shared _instance As SingletonClass

Public Shared Function GetSingletonClass() As SingletonClass
  If isNothing(_instance) Then
    _instance = New SingletonClass()
  End If
  Return _instance
End Function

Private Sub New()
'' Create the instance here
End Sub

End Class`

As you can see, since the constructor is private, it is not accessible from anywhere outside of class SingletonClass, and since class SingletonClass holds a static reference to it's instance, it means that every time you write SingletonClass.GetSingletonClass() in your application you get the same instance. 
This design pattern solves both of your problems in a simple, elegant, and well known architecture.

**Update**

I've recently read a [great article about different ways to implement singleton patterns](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx). It turns out that my above specific implementation is not so good, as it is not thread safe. The code examples in this article are C#, but it should be very easy to change them to VB.Net. If you are using .Net 4 or higher, I would recommend going with the 6th version - using .NET 4's Lazy type.
It is both thread safe and lazy loading, two advantages that the implementation I've written doesn't have.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that in my app!

Comment: "private" gives me an error so I used Shared instead and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Oh, sorry, It's been a while since my VB.Net days. I currently write c# most of the time. What Shared means in VB.Net is the same as static in c# - a member of the class and not the instance.